# Deploy AngularJs app an Zend Framework 2.2 app in same url

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework

I have developed a website with PHP Zend Framework 2.2 backend (API) and an AngularJS / Bootstrap front end.

In local mode, I am using 2 apache virtual host to run this website and it works fine.
But, now, I have to deploy the website in a production like environment (OVH) and all my content must be placed under the same folder (/www).

What is the best way to do that ?

- use subdomain : one for back : back.mywebsite.fr and one for front : mywebsite.fr : do you know how to do in OVH
- merge my AngularJS app into zend-framework/public directory ? (I will choose this solution only if there is no other solution because it means I have to modify my code)
- install the AngularJS on the root folder and add a specific routes into app.js in order to allow back end HTTP calls ? (In local mode with grunt, I am already using node proxy but I don't know how to do that with AngularJS only)
- other way ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you share what did you did to solve the problem ?